# Django REST Framework getting object ID back from hyperlinked identity field

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am having difficulty getting the URL (or any sort of ID) back from the `validated_data` when using a `HyperlinkedIdentityField`. I need the URL because I am doing writable nested representations and I want to know if the nested representation refers to an existing object (url specified) or a new object (url not specified). I have read the [example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update) in the docs about customizing `ListSerializer` update but that seems to rely on the client sending an `id` that does not exist, which does not work for me as I want to use URLs instead. I have checked `validated_data` for a top-level (not nested) object with a `HyperlinkedIdentityField` and the ID is not exposed there either.

**EDIT**: I am now aware this is because `HyperlinkedIdentityField` sets the `read_only` attribute and read-only fields are skipped when generating validated data. Tips welcome on how to get around this.

I have two models in this phonebook app: `Entry` and `Phone`. An `Entry` has multiple `Phone`s. Just in case this is relevant, the model code is as follows:

```
from django.db import models


class Entry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Phone(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Entry, related_name='phones')
```

My serializer definitions follow:

```
class PhoneListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def update(self, instance, validated_data): 
        print repr(validated_data)
        url_of = lambda p : self.child.to_representation(p)['url']
        existing_instances = { url_of(p): p for p in instance }
        existing_submitted_instances = { item['url']: item for item in validated_data if 'url' in item }
        new_submitted_instances = [ item for item in validated_data if 'url' not in item ]
        urls_to_delete = existing_instances.viewkeys() - existing_submitted_instances.viewkeys()                                                       
        objects_to_delete = [existing_instances[u] for u in urls_to_delete if u in existing_instances]                                                 
        objects_to_update = [(existing_instances[u], p) for u, p in six.iteritems(existing_submitted_instances) if u in existing_instances]

        result = []
        for o in objects_to_delete:
            o.delete()
        for existing, data in objects_to_update:                          
            result.append(self.child.update(existing, data))
        for data in new_submitted_instances:                              
            data['parent'] = self.root.instance
            result.append(self.child.create(data))
        return result

class PhoneSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='phone', lookup_field='id')
    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        list_serializer_class = PhoneListSerializer
        fields = ('type', 'number', 'url')

class EntrySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='entry', lookup_field='id')
    phones = PhoneSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'phones')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print repr(validated_data)
        # pop this first so super does not complain about writable nested
        # serializers. we will update phones ourselves.
        phone_data = validated_data.pop('phones', [])
        phones_field = self.fields['phones']

        instance = super(EntrySerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

        phones_field.update(instance.phones.all(), phone_data)

        return instance

    def create(self, validated_data):
        phone_data = validated_data.pop('phones', [])
        new_entry = Entry.objects.create(**validated_data)
        # TODO atomically do this
        for phone_validated_data in phone_data:
            Phone.objects.create(parent=new_entry, **phone_validated_data)
        return new_entry
```

Currently getting data out works, but resubmitting the data (even with the URL) results in all phones of an entry being deleted and then recreated with new IDs.

**EDIT**: attempting to use a `HyperlinkedRelatedField` (and a `ModelSerializer` instead of a `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`) gets further (the field succeeds in pulling an object out), but still fails when the serializer calls `fields.set_value`

Code:

```
class PhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        required=False, view_name='phone', lookup_field='id',
        queryset=Phone.objects, source='*')
```

This fails since it eventually calls `rest_framework.fields.set_value(validated_data, [], <Phone object>)` and it will call `validated_data.update(<Phone object>)` which fails with 'Phone object is not iterable'.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...snip...]
  File "/app/phonebook_be/views.py", line 41, in entry
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 191, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 371, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 404, in to_internal_value
    validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 522, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 552, in to_internal_value
    validated = self.child.run_validation(item)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 371, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 414, in to_internal_value
    set_value(ret, field.source_attrs, validated_value)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 96, in set_value
    dictionary.update(value)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 568, in update
    for key, value in other:
TypeError: 'Phone' object is not iterable
```

Other attempts:

`source='id'`: results in error when rendering

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...snip...]
  File "/app/phonebook_be/views.py", line 18, in entries
    json_data = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 470, in data
    ret = super(Serializer, self).data
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 217, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 439, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 572, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 439, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 264, in to_representation
    return self.get_url(value, self.view_name, request, format)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 202, in get_url
    lookup_value = getattr(obj, self.lookup_field)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently manually comparing URLs. That works however there are some issues:

```
url_of = lambda p : self.child.to_representation(p)['url']
existing_instances = { url_of(p): p for p in instance }
```

the second line is expensive since the `instance` is a queryset so as soon as you will have lots of data, that can become a memory hog since you will be creating a dict for all the instances matching queryset.

Instead of doing that, DRF natively supports parsing URLs in order to get the identity object:

```
class PhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
         required=False,
         view_name='phone',
         lookup_field='id',
     )
```

Notice the use of `HyperlinkedRelatedField`. Unlike `HyperlinkedIdentityField` (which subclasses `HyperlinkedRelatedField`), `HyperlinkedRelatedField` is not read-only. It is capable of parsing the URL and getting the model out of the URL itself by reversing the URL and then using the kwargs in the url to lookup the object in db. As a result, you can rely on that behavior to lookup existing objects in db. Notice that the field altogether is optional which allows the client of the API to omit it in which case URL will not be parsed hence a new object can be created.

```
class PhoneListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def update(self, instance, validated_data): 
        to_update = filter(lambda i: i.get('url'), validated_data)
        to_create = filter(lambda i: not i.get('url'), validated_data)
        data = []
        for i in to_update:
            data.append(self.child.update(i['url'], i))
        for i in to_create:
            data.append(self.child.create(i))
        return data
```

Hopefully this helps. Note that I did this from memory so there might be some things to watch out for but this concept should generally work.

Finally there are some docs about the `HyperlinkedRelatedField` - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried it, got further, but still does not work (updated the post with what happens).

Comment: can you link to traceback? I didnt understand what is your current failure

Comment: I added the tracebacks to the post.

Comment: hmm. not sure. something odd is going on. I would recommend to debug some of the DRF code. could be bug or usage could be slightly wrong.

Comment: I eventually worked around this with a write-only field (in other answer). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So to work around this I created a write-only field (inspired by `HiddenField`) on the `PhoneSerializer` that takes its value from the submitted 'url' value:

```
class WriteOnlySynonymField(serializers.Field):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['default'] = serializers.empty
        kwargs['required'] = False
        kwargs['write_only'] = True
        self.synonym_for = kwargs.pop('synonym_for')
        super(WriteOnlySynonymField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_value(self, dictionary):
        return dictionary.get(self.synonym_for, serializers.empty)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return data


class PhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = MultiKeyHyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='phone',
        lookup_kwarg_to_field={'id': 'id', 'entry_id': 'parent_id'})
    submitted_url = WriteOnlySynonymField(synonym_for='url')

    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        list_serializer_class = PhoneListSerializer
        fields = ('type', 'number', 'url', 'submitted_url')
```

And the relevant bits of the list serializer update changes slightly to use the new field name:

```
existing_submitted_instances = {item['submitted_url']: item
                                for item in validated_data
                                if 'submitted_url' in item}
new_submitted_instances = [item for item in validated_data
                           if 'submitted_url' not in item]
```